# How to throw errors from one service and catch it in another component in Angular2

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have used Firebase for authenticaton purpose.

This is the code for authentication

```
export class AuthService {

      signupUser(email:string,password:string){
        firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).catch((error)=>{
          console.log(error);
        })
      }
```

This is code for signup in signup.Component.ts

```
onSignup(form:NgForm){
  const email=form.value.email;
  const password=form.value.password;
  this.authService.signupUser(email,password);
  }
```

So instead of printing an error, I would like to throw an error and catch it in signup component so that I can use that error and display a flash message to the user. How can I do that? Can somebody please solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just return the promise, and let the caller attach their own handlers:

```
signupUser(email:string,password:string){
  return firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password);
}
```

Then the caller can do:

```
this.authService.signupUser(email,password).catch(...);
```